# how to avoid file's to be copy by scp from other machine

Tags: linux, bash, scp

how to avoid file/s to be copied by scp from other machine

example

my machine - `example.org`:

- from some other OS machine:

  ```
  scp -rp example.org:/var/example.txt   .
  ```

Comment: Inflammatory political comments in the questions are not acceptable. This is a technical site for pro admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scp` relies on `ssh` for connecting; in other words, what you really want is to secure your `ssh` service/access to the machine. Some ideas:

- use a firewall to only enable your trusted hosts to connect to port 22 (ssh);
- use a two factor authentication method, the most common being a password-protected RSA/DSA key for ssh authentication;
- do not enable `root` login and configure appropriate file permissions (denying access to the most important files)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the command you pasted, `scp` is going to use local machine's user to `ssh` and copy the file over. Did you try to set special permissions with `chmod`/`chown` so that file cannot be accessed by other users?

If you are looking for something more advanced, try dig into `setuid`/`setgid`.

Hope it helps.